# Crop rectangle from a image (entities from a database schema)

Tags: python, opencv

i have this code, i need to crop each entity from different types of database schema, workbench, sqlserver phpmyadmin etc. this code should detect, draw and crop each entity but in same case it doesnt work.

```
import cv2
import os
import pytesseract
from PIL import Image

#obtengo la direccion donde se encuentra los recortes

lista = os.listdir('C:/Users/Usuario/Documents/Deteccion de Objetos/recortes')

#busco la ultima carpeta creada de los recortes

ultimo = lista.pop()
convertido = int(ultimo)

path = 'C:/Users/Usuario/Documents/Deteccion de Objetos/recortes/' + ultimo
image = cv2.imread("C:/Users/Usuario/Documents/Deteccion de Objetos/imagenes/Nuevacarpeta/sqlserver.png")
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (5,5), 0)
thresh = cv2.threshold(blur, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]


cnts = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
for c in cnts:
    area = cv2.contourArea(c)
    if area < 5000:
        cv2.drawContours(thresh, [c], -1, (0,0,0), -1)


close_kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (5,5))
close = 255 - cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, close_kernel, iterations=6)
cnts = cv2.findContours(close, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
for c in cnts:
    area = cv2.contourArea(c)
    if area < 15000:
        cv2.drawContours(close, [c], -1, (0,0,0), -1)


close = 255 - close
open_kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (20,20))
opening = cv2.morphologyEx(close, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, open_kernel, iterations=3)

# Busca los contornos y dibuja los resultados
ROI_number = 0
cnts = cv2.findContours(opening, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
for c in cnts:
    cv2.drawContours(image, [c], -1, (36,255,12), 3)
    #aqui se realiza el recorte de cada entidad
    x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(c)
    ROI = image[y:y+h, x:x+w]
    cv2.imwrite(os.path.join(path , 'imagen_{}.png'.format(ROI_number)), ROI)
    cv2.rectangle(image,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(36,255,12),2)
    ROI_number += 1

nuevo = str(convertido + 1).zfill(7)

os.chdir('C:/Users/Usuario/Documents/Deteccion de Objetos/recortes')
os.mkdir(nuevo)

print("Cantidad de entidades ", len(cnts))
cv2.imshow('thresh', thresh)
cv2.imshow('opening', opening)
cv2.imshow('image', image)
cv2.waitKey()
```

for example i get this result from a sqlserve schema:

[image]

i get this from this image in workbench:

[image]

i get this from a phpmyadmin schema: in this case doesn't work anything.

[image]

but in this case it works:

[image]

could you help me to draw correctly the contours of each entity from any schema?

those are the pictures that don't work.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Post your input images so that others can test your code. Check your thresh images to see that they look as expected. Also perhaps your area thresholds need to be adjusted for different data sources.

Comment: ok i will do, thanks